# Is startUpdatingMyLocation mandatory to call the location manager's didUpdateToLocation method in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I need a clarification that. Is startUpdatingMyLocation method mandatory to call didUpdateToLocation? isn't the didUpdateToLocation method automatically called when the location is updated?

Guy's please clear my clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documents state

> Start standard location services by calling the startUpdatingLocation
>   method. This service is most appropriate for applications that need
>   more fine-grained control over the delivery of location events.
>   Specifically, it takes into account the values in the desiredAccuracy
>   and distanceFilter property to determine when to deliver new events.
>   The precision of the standard location services are needed by
>   navigation applications or any application where high-precision
>   location data or a regular stream of updates is required. However,
>   these services typically require the location-tracking hardware to be
>   enabled for longer periods of time, which can result in higher power
>   usage.
>
> For applications that do not need a regular stream of location events,
>   consider using the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method to
>   start the delivery of events instead. This method is more appropriate
>   for the majority of applications that just need an initial user
>   location fix and need updates only when the user moves a significant
>   distance. This interface delivers new events only when it detects
>   changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less
>   frequent updates and significantly lower power usage.
>
> Regardless of which location service you use, location data is
>   reported to your application via the location manager’s associated
>   delegate object. Because it can take several seconds to return an
>   initial location, the location manager typically delivers the
>   previously cached location data immediately and then delivers more
>   up-to-date location data as it becomes available. Therefore it is
>   always a good idea to check the timestamp of any location object
>   before taking any actions. If both location services are enabled
>   simultaneously, they deliver events using the same set of delegate
>   methods.

So you can use any of the two , either `startUpdatingLocation` or `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to get the location updates but you will have to call any one of these for the delegate method being called. (IMHO)

Comment: Is it enough to call the startUpdatingLocation method single time.

Comment: Yes, it is. It then keeps on calling the delegate method if there is any significant change in the values.(I guess you can also specify this.)

Comment: But is it mandatory to use stopUpdatingLocation any where ..??

Comment: NO, its not but you should stop it as soon as you are done with location values, because location updates take quite a lot of battery and processing power. Like if you are on the same view controller and you have the co-ordinates and you don't need them on a regular basis then you should stop the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Start standard location services by calling the startUpdatingLocation method. This service is most appropriate for applications that need more fine-grained control over the delivery of location events. Specifically, it takes into account the values in the desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter property to determine when to deliver new events. The precision of the standard location services are needed by navigation applications or any application where high-precision location data or a regular stream of updates is required. However, these services typically require the location-tracking hardware to be enabled for longer periods of time, which can result in higher power usage.

For applications that do not need a regular stream of location events, consider using the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method to start the delivery of events instead. This method is more appropriate for the majority of applications that just need an initial user location fix and need updates only when the user moves a significant distance. This interface delivers new events only when it detects changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates and significantly lower power usage.

Regardless of which location service you use, location data is reported to your application via the location manager’s associated delegate object. Because it can take several seconds to return an initial location, the location manager typically delivers the previously cached location data immediately and then delivers more up-to-date location data as it becomes available. Therefore it is always a good idea to check the timestamp of any location object before taking any actions. If both location services are enabled simultaneously, they deliver events using the same set of delegate methods.